# locate is not locating the file present in the current directory

Tags: locate, distribution-media

That media is another hard disk in the computer. What is the way to locate things there?

[image]

Comment: `locate` uses a database that is usually updated once per day. When did you mount that drive?

Comment: Okay, @n.st I will use updatedb and then try again. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

`locate` uses a database that is usually updated once per day <sup>(e.g. by `/etc/cron.daily/mlocate`)</sup>, so changes and newly mounted filesystems won't show up immediately.
Run `updatedb` to trigger an immediate re-scan.

Additionally, `/media` and similar "volatile" paths are usually excluded — look for `PRUNEPATHS` in `/etc/updatedb.conf` and adapt it to your needs.